# In ignition fortress, how to get components of an universal joint in system plugins?

Tags: joint, plugin, ignition-fortress

I'm having problems in developing a system plugin for Ignition.
In the case the robot has a universal joint, creating/updating component data related to the entity, returns something like:

```
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [Wrn] [Physics.cc:2002] There is a mismatch in the degrees of freedom between Joint [wheel_front_right_steer_spin(Entity=20)] and its JointVelocityCmd component. The joint has 2 while the component has 1.
```

The snippet of the code to create/update component velocity is:

```
Entity joint;

auto pos_component = _ecm.Component<components::JointPosition>(joint);
auto vel_component = _ecm.Component<components::JointVelocityCmd>(joint);

if (pos_component == nullptr || vel_component == nullptr) {
    _ecm.CreateComponent(joint, components::JointPosition());
    _ecm.CreateComponent(joint, components::JointVelocityCmd());
} else {
    vel_component->Data()[dataPtr->joint_index] = dataPtr->target_vel;

    ignwarn << "pos_component size = " << pos_component->Data().size() << std::endl;
    ignwarn << "vel_component size = " << vel_component->Data().size() << std::endl;
}
```

The "pos_component" has dimension 2 while "vel_component" has dimension 1 even though they come from the same joint entity.